Where does Fujitsu Scansnap Home stored unsaved pdfs?
I am using Scansnap Home scan software for the Fujitsu/PFU (now Ricoh) scanners (such as ix500/ix1600).
I am using the scan profile "Scan to Folder" which pops up a Window to save your PDF after a scan.
Yesterday night, a Windows update restarted my PC and I had a PDF unsaved in such a "Scan to Folder" window open as shown below:

Question: Where can I find my temporary/unsaved PDF file? I have already shredded the original paper copy.

ScanSnap (SshRegister.exe) writes PDFs temporarily to the following folder:
%LocalAppData%\Temp\ScanSnap Home\SshRegisterConnection\

i.e. C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Temp\ScanSnap Home\SshRegisterConnection\...

